# Installing Buddypress as a folder on Wordpress blog and face redirect issue

Tags: wordpress, forum, buddypress

I installed Buddypress as a folder on my wordpress blog. (http://.com//)

But all the pages (activity, members, groups..) are going to wordpress and show 404 page normally.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Erman

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I am writing the way how i solved so people who will face the same problem, can solve too.

My .htaccess file doesn't exist -i don't know why-. So i check it on permission settings and create it.